# Accessing css/js files outside of htdocs (in Xampp)? (Windows)

Tags: javascript, html, css, xampp, htdocs

I'm just wondering if it is possible to use css/js files from outside the webroot on a Windows 7 machine. If I try to right now, Chrome console says not allowed to load local resource. Is there a way to go around this?

If I have the following file structure:

```
C:
    xampp
        htdocs (webroot)
            myproject
                index.php
    otherFolder
        css
            style.css
        js
            main.js
```

Is there a way to get index.php to use style.css and main.js?

Comment: I would just add the otherFolder location to a new virtual host. Web servers don't give you access to the file system, and in a production environment there would be no way to make this happen. Essentially, you want to cross-link the CSS/JS files from another host, which is entirely possible.

Comment: What about using symbolic links? http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/

Comment: @seemly It seems possible with symbolic links, thanks.

Comment: @aaronburrows Can you elaborate on what you mean by production environment? This site isn't going public; its just for our building, thus the site is hosted on this server running xampp.

Comment: I mean that if you publish the site "publicly", even for internal users, you won't be able to access the file system directly. Every file served needs to come from a web server (hostname). So I would either move the file into the webroot or create a second virtual host in order to access those files.